# QSound::play doesn't work after the call moveToThread

Tags: c++, qt

I'm using worker thread which put into separated thread by call

```
worker.moveToThread(myThread);
```

I need to play simple wav in some cases inside worker ,
I use static call for that:

` QSound::play("qrc:/sounds/warning.wav");

if I do this in worker constructor (before moveToThread) it works fine,
however if I put this call into thread function :

```
void Worker::threadFunc() {
     QSound::play("qrc:/sounds/warning.wav");
    ...
```

then it doesn't work - no sound play
any idea how to work properly with wav playing in non-GUI threads?

Comment: Can you step through it with debugger?

Comment: what exactly you mean ? into play() ?

Comment: Yeah, if you plan to code with Qt you'll have to get used to debugging their code, sooner or later.

Comment: According to the official documentation on `QSound` playing a sound is asynchronous, which means that it won't block your GUI. There is no reason to play a sound in a different thread. A sound does not belong there since it's part of the GUI so it should be triggered within the main thread where the GUI resides. My recommendation is to simply emit a signal from your thread (once it finishes doing whatever your worker is doing) that you can capture through a slot in your widget.

Comment: if I link threadWorker event signal with some gui slot there is the same result: it called and play() is also called within a slot but I don't hear the sound. and the same if I do this before moveToThread it works fine

Comment: Have you tried using a QSound object instead of the static method? (Make sure the object is actually created by the worker QThread, e.g. connect the QThread's *started()* signal to a member slot of your worker object, and create/use QSound there).

Comment: I'm using a little bit different log: worker object (it's not inherited form Qthread but uses this) has a signal which informs its owner (QWidget-based in the case) about the event which requires a sound effect, so Qsound object created in parent (for worker) object and attempt to play this located in parent too

Comment: and yes , I'm currently using Qsound object instead of static method.

Comment: seems I need to read Qt slot/signal mechanism with more attention, I've replaced Direct with Auto (signal type in connect() ) and now all works as desired . thanks a lot guys!